Best 2 out 3 and 1 and done double elimination braket
How does everyone do the championship game for a best 2 out 3 winners bracket and 1 loss losers bracket? The way we have always done it is the once the losers win the losers bracket they then must play best 2 out of 3 against the winner of the winners bracket. If they win 2 games then they must beat that team one more time to win the tournament. But I have been told now that they have to win the 1st game and then if they do they must then play a best 2 out of 3.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That's just how double-loss knock-out competitions work!
The top winner has to lose twice to be knocked out, but the top loser is knocked out as soon as they get their second loss in the last knock-out match.
That means the top loser must first give the top winner a loss, before they are on equal standing, and then begin the best-of-three round to determine overall winner.

That sounds like setting the losing team up to... well, lose. Or at least it's a disadvantage.

They shouldn't have lost the first time, then. They are at a disadvantage because they played worse than the opponents did, throughout the competition.

Good point. Didn't think of that.
